# caption package: vertical space at top of page

Tags: captions, vertical-spacing

I include pics in my document using just:

```latex
\begin{center}
\includegraphics{...}
\end{center}
```

However, I want captions with the `captions` package and correct hyperlink anchors, so I end up with something like:

```latex
\begin{center}
\captionsetup{type=figure}
\includegraphics{...}
\caption{asdf}
\label{fig1}
\end{center}
```

Now the problem is the vertical space this seems to produce if the image is included **at the top of a page**. Otherwise, things are fine. Use the **MWE** below to see what I mean.

The MWE shows two workarounds as well, but I'm unhappy with both.

How do I get this right?

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage[hypcap=true]{caption}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\listoffigures
\newpage

\begin{center}%
\captionsetup{type=figure}%
\includegraphics[width=.25\linewidth]{example-image}
\caption{asdf}
\label{fig1}
\end{center}
Why do I get vertical space above figure \ref{fig1}
\begin{center}%
\captionsetup{type=figure}%
\includegraphics[width=.25\linewidth]{example-image}
\caption{asdf}
\label{fig2}
\end{center}
Looks good here for \ref{fig2}. So must have something to do with top of page.

\newpage
\begin{center}
\captionsetup{type=figure}
\vspace{-3.5mm}
\includegraphics[width=.25\linewidth]{example-image}
\caption{asdf}
\label{fig3}
\end{center}
A workaround with some vspace for figure \ref{fig3}, however, the link anchor is now not optimal.

\newpage
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\centering\captionsetup{type=figure}
\includegraphics[width=.25\linewidth]{example-image}
\caption{asdf}
\label{fig4}
\end{minipage}
Using a minipage works as described in docs:

\url{https://mirror.clientvps.com/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/caption/caption.pdf}

But now the spacing between caption and the text is too tight.


\newpage
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\centering\captionsetup{type=figure}
\includegraphics[width=.25\linewidth]{example-image}
\caption{asdf}
\label{fig5}
\end{minipage}
\vskip\baselineskip
\noindent So another workaround...

\end{document}
```

Comment: I believe that the `\caption{...}` command is used with the `figure` environment. You could then use `\begin{figure}[htbp]....\end{figure}` -- however, this is a dangerous and exciting path if your figure won't fit in the page...

Comment: The extra line is being caused by `\captionsetup`.  You can move it below the `\includegraphics`, you can use `\captionof{figure}{...},`, or you can use `\begin{figure}[ht]` as you should have all along.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I know that `\captionsetup` is somehow the reason. I cannot move it below `\includegraphics` in order to get link anchor right. This is the intended use according to the docs.
@Roadbug Of course a `figure` environment would be a solution, but I deliberately do not want anything floating.

Comment: In order to put a hypertarget above the top of the image seems to  require adding a blank line.  Otherwise it would wind up above the text area.

Comment: @JohnKormylo yeah, I think I will go with my 2nd workaround of a minipage environment + some vertical space below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Minipage is needed but is a rather low-level environment, spacing must be added explicitly. This can be done with vspace commands, but also e.g. with
center or use float which handles also the spacing

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage[hypcap=true]{caption}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}

\listoffigures
\newpage
\vspace*{35\baselineskip}
\begin{center}%
\captionsetup{type=figure}%
\includegraphics[width=.25\linewidth]{example-image}
\caption{asdf}
\label{fig1}
\end{center}
You need a minipage to avoid that caption and picture gets separated, see \ref{fig1}

\newpage 
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\centering\captionsetup{type=figure}
\includegraphics[width=.25\linewidth]{example-image}
\caption{asdf}
\label{fig2}
\end{minipage}

But now the spacing between caption and the text is too tight.


\newpage
\begin{center}%
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\centering\captionsetup{type=figure}
\includegraphics[width=.25\linewidth]{example-image}
\caption{asdf}
\label{fig3}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}

Minipage is a rather low-level environment, spacing must be added explicitly. This can be done with vspace commands, but also e.g. with
center or use float which handles also the spacing, see \ref{fig4}

\newpage
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.25\linewidth]{example-image}
\caption{asdd}
\label{fig4}
\end{figure}

with some text behind
\end{document}
```

Comment: The additional center environment does the trick for me, thanks.